# Data not inserting into database, it shows empty columns in table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I have form inside panel and I am inserting data into the database by using a stored procedure from form. It doesn't throw any error, but it is not showing data in the database. Code works successfully but columns in tables are empty.

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[spDREG]
    (@pname varchar(250),
     @spname varchar(250),
     @age int,
     @spage int,
     @cat varchar(50),
     @mno bigint,
     @emlid varchar(250),
     @years varchar(50)
    )
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dregid INT = @@identity

    INSERT INTO DREG(P_NAME, SECP_NAME, AGE, AGET, CAT, MOB_NO, EMAILD, YEARS)
    VALUES(@pname, @spname, @age, @spage, @cat, @mno, @emlid, @years)
END
```

This is my code behind

```
protected void Dsbtn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string psname ="spDREG"; ;
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(psname,con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", TextBox1.Text.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spname", TextBox2.Text.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", TextBox22.Text.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spage", TextBox24.Text.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", DropDownList1.Text.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mno", TextBox4.Text.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emlid", TextBox5.Text.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@years", DropDownList2.Text.ToString());

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        dreglbl.Text = "You have successfully registered";
    }
```

This is my design part

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="dan" class="npan" Width="900px" Height="500px">
    <h3 style="text-align: center" class="panhed">Please Fill This Form TO Participate(Dance Registration)</h3>
    <div id="snam" runat="server" class="nam">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Name of participant:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="txtcls" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>                                     
        <asp:Button ID="addm" class="addbtn" runat="server" autopostback="true" Text="Add member" OnClick="addm_Click" />
    </div>
    <div id="Div3" runat="server" class="nams">
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" autopostback="true" Text="Name of 2nd participant:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" CssClass="txtscls" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div id="Div29" runat="server" class="nams">
        <asp:Label ID="Label27" runat="server" Text="Age:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox22" CssClass="agtxt" placeholder="1st" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox24" CssClass="agstxt" placeholder="2nd" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div id="Div2" runat="server" class="cate">
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Select Category:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1" Class="drpd" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="22">select</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Ss">Solo</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Dd">Duet</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Gg">Group</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div id="divv" class="mobn" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Mobile No:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" CssClass="mobtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div id="Div6" runat="server" class="eml">
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="E-Mail:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" CssClass="emtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div id="Div7" runat="server" class="yer">
        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Select Year:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList2" Class="drpds">
            <asp:ListItem>select</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>First</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Second</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Third</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>other</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div id="Div8" runat="server" class="btndiv">
        <asp:Button ID="Dsbtn" runat="server" Class="Btncss" Text="Submit" OnClick="Dsbtn_click" />
        <asp:Label ID="dreglbl" runat="server" Text="label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Please solve it guys. Thank you

Comment: did you check the text box values by debugging your .net code once the event has been hit?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: what should i do now.i am facing same problem in other panel

Comment: What does your connection string to the database look like?

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ADMIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=festopedia;Integrated Security=True");
    my connection string

Comment: Use SQL Server Profiler to see if the stored procedure is executed with the expected values.

Comment: Aside: You probably don't want to pick up [`@@Identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql) out of the blue and use the value for anything other than seeding a random number sequence. Since you don't know what statement set the value, or what trigger it might have been hiding in, you ought to find a more suitable means of passing or generating a suitable value.

Comment: except id other columns can have null value but when i insert data through sql it throws an error that it expect value.spname